# Do you think a fluid website should have limits for its width?

Tags: html, css, web

Do you think a fluid website should have limits for its width (such as min-width and max-width, and hacks for IE)? Well, that's because screen resolutions may be too high which is not that good for reading text contents. What'd you say?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I think there's often a good case for `max-width`.

Making a website hugely wide is likely to reduce its readability due to over-long text lines - not in all cases, but in many.

And whether people like it or not, achieving a truly flexible layout, within the constraints of the information you're presenting and its visual design, can be unreasonably difficult.  `max-width` can help to reach a  compromise.

My site here: http://entrian.com/source-search does exactly what you describe, and IMHO it's a good compromise between flexibility in a narrow browser and readability in a wide one.

Answer (score 2):

There are upper and lower limits for the length of a line of text, after which it becomes very hard to read for the average user. [This](http://www.viget.com/advance/the-line-length-misconception/) post talks about it in depth, but the answer seems to be that anything over 100 characters per line should be avoided.

As long as you stay within these limits I would say that you don't need to cap the width of the site, just individual text sections. As usual the disclaimer of '*it depends on what you are trying to achieve*' will apply.

Comment: I would add only one thought - the wider the text column, the higher should be the line-height (interline). At least that's what I've learned at work :)

And you can't control this without JS (and probably messing with the nice design of your website).

So, my conclusion is - you cannot design an efficent website layout without a max-width.

Answer (score -2):

This is not really programming related. But take this is site an example. Does it look fluid to you? And it has fixed width... I think it depends on the site, it needs to be decided looking at the characteristics and outcome.